# React router's useLocation is throwing an invalid hook use error and I don't understand why

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

Other hooks in my components work normally, but useLocation throws an invalid hook call. To make sure this wasn't due to some obscure interference from weird logic in the rest of the app, I reduced the problem further and further untill I basically ended up with the example from the useLocation docs on https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks and it still doesn't work. Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
// import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, useLocation, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
// import './index.scss'
// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'
// const dotenv = require('dotenv')
// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

function usePageViews() {
    let location = useLocation()
    console.log('===location===', location)
}

function App() {
    usePageViews()
    return (
        <Switch>
            ...
            {/* <Route path="*" component={() => <div>TEST</div>}></Route> */}
        </Switch>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I tryed all sorts of things but I don't know how to reduce the problem down from here. I used this hook before in a different project and it worked fine. I tried deleting my node_modules and package-lock.json and re-installing the packages and the same error persists. Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "personal_website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.23",
    "@types/node": "12.12.11",
    "@types/react": "16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

EDIT: It's clearly something to do with project setup. Obviously this code works for other people otherwise it wouldn't be there in the docs, and I set up a fresh project with the same code and it works. It's just that I have no clue what part of the project setup could cause this kind of issue.

Comment: Can you create live example with this problem? It would be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and it works without problems. Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-igaaur?file=src%2Findex.js).

Maybe your `usePageViews` function isn't a valid React Component on your call context, which means that hooks won't work inside of it. You should do:

```js
<usePageViews />
```

instead of:

```js
usePageViews()
```

of course, this within the App return.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tracked it down. Turns out, I had react-router-dom installed further up in the project hierarchy (this app is the client app and it's inside of a larger project containing several apps and with its own package.json) but not in the local package.json. As you can see from the project.json i posted, react-router-dom isn't actually in there. The Router still worked, apparently succesfully working with the parent's node_modules but the hook threw this error which is very weird and unexpected. Hopefully this helps someone else having a simmilar problem.